# how to use webkit framework in cocoa touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview

i wanna use webkit framework in my app to implement web page show.

now first i wanna user `NSURLConnection`  connection method to get the requst data.
then i use a  webView `loadData:urlData` the push the data to the webview show.

now debug in this method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType
```

find open a new url request like `url = about:blank`  in the webview delegate.

i dont know why can open a new blank url request during this requst.

who can tell me why? thanks

Comment: Your English is a bit hard to understand... could you explain what is exactly the problem? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: UIWebView is a Cocoa Touch class, not a Cocoa class. If you're using Cocoa Touch, you can't access WebKit directly—you can only access it through UIWebView, which is part of UIKit.

Comment: You don't need to open about:blank, it comes that way.

Comment: Also, you really should accept some answers. Surely one of the other six questions you've asked with answers was helpful.

Comment: ok,i know some way to improve this question. thanks.